# Is there any way access Nest devices with a Google Workspace (G Suite) account?

Tags: google-workspace, nest-api, nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I am trying to use the Device Access Console sandbox using a Google Workspace (G Suite) account. When I try to retrieve permissions for a Nest device I run into an error stating I need to be added as a member to the Google Home account associated with the device (see [here](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/pcm?authuser=2#no_access_to_partner)).

However, it seems that Google Workspace accounts cannot be added as a member Google Nest Home accounts (see [here](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9297676?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhy-cant-my-account-be-migrated-why-do-i-get-an-error)).

I am wondering if there's any possible way to access Nest devices in the Device Access Console with a Google Workspace account. Is this perhaps possible when using the Device Access Console for commercial development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible at the moment.